# I am trying to run a block of code in c but it doesn't execute the way I expect/want

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code of C program. In this application I prompt user to choose any computer model from the list on the screen.  If the user chooses Dell then prompt bluh bluh bluh and if user choose any other model then execute bluh bluh. Well the case is that after compiling, when I run the application, it doesn't respond the way I want. After `if` condition, `else if` and `else` are not executed whether `if` condition is not true. I too use cs50 library to get string from user which I can also do from scanf.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main (void)
{
    char first_Pc[] = "Dell"; 
    char second_Pc[] = "Intel";
    char third_Pc[] = "Max";

    {
        printf("Please Specify your choice. \n");
        printf("We have Dell, Intel And Max computers:\n");

        string userChoice = GetString();

            if ("userChoice == first_Pc", &first_Pc)
            {
                printf("Nice Choice! Your Dell worths $100.");
            }
            else if ("userChoice == second_Pc", &second_Pc)
            {
                printf("You prefer Intel computers! They are smart. You have to pay $150.");
            }
            else if ("userChoice == third_Pc", &third_Pc)
            {
                printf("Max computers are really superfast! They worth $200");
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("You didn't choose any from our stored models!");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `string` as a type there, but that's neither C (`char*`) nor C++ (`std::string`). Further, considering the fact that you tagged this with both languages, which is a mistake, you should first decide on a language and then extract a minimal example as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `string` is a type defined in header `cs50.h`

Comment: Your crystal ball must be better than mine, @CoolGuy. ;)

Comment: And that's why definitions like `string` can be a bad thing... You can compare fundamental data types using equality operators like `==` and relational operators like `<` and `>=`, but a function is required for comparing aggregate types like arrays or structures. Since a string in C is an array of characters, you must use a function. Anything like `typedef char *string;` hides that fact and makes `string` seem like a fundamental data type, which isn't true in C.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune: I just say `typedef TCHAR* LPTSTR`

Comment: @user877329 Then you're doing it wrong. Unicode is `LPWSTR` and is compared using `wcscmp` or `wcscoll`. ;-)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Did I ever say that I like MS conventions. They typedef all pointer types. But perhaps it made sense back in the good old days of NEAR and FAR pointers.

Comment: @user877329 My point is that I worry about the confusion `cs50.h` creates. `LPTSTR` for example is a good sign that might make even a beginner wonder, "Why is that data type name in all caps when `int`, `float`, etc. are all in lowercase?" unlike `string` from the `cs50.h` header, which makes that type definition seem like a native data type. It might make sense in the CS50 appliance perhaps (for which it was intended), but not in general C programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing strings in C - strcmp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027786/comparing-strings-in-c-strcmp)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare strings using `==` ( You can, but it actually compares pointers and not the actual content ). But your attempt of comparing looks awkward. Use `strcmp` from `string.h` It returns 0 if both its arguments hold the same content.

So change

```
if ("userChoice == first_Pc", &first_Pc)
else if ("userChoice == second_Pc", &second_Pc)
else if ("userChoice == third_Pc", &third_Pc)
```

to

```
if (strcmp(userChoice, first_Pc) == 0)
else if (strcmp(userChoice, second_Pc) == 0)
else if (strcmp(userChoice, third_Pc) == 0)
```

and don't forget to `#include <string.h>`!

---

Here is an explanation of what you were doing.

Here:

```
if ("userChoice == first_Pc", &first_Pc)
```

there is some condition and and `if`. You know what an `if` does so lets skip that part. The condition here is `"userChoice == first_Pc", &first_Pc`. The first part is a string literal `"..."` (the contents in them don't matter) and the second part is the address of `first_Pc`, a `char(*)[5]`, seperated by a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

The comma operator evaluates its left operand and returns the right. In this case, the string literal is evaluated and discarded and the address of `first_Pc` is returned. Since it is not `NULL`, the condition becomes true and the `if` executes.

Comment: You should mention that a string literal like "userChoice == first_Pc" never performs an operation.

Comment: @user877329 Done. Looks ok?

Comment: Well a thousand to all of you. It worked for me. And I am very new to C and trying to enclose my dump ideas into programming which just result in what you have seen. Thanks

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, that is fine